# Point of dropping weights in mini batch for purpose of regularization

Tags: neural-network, regularization, mini-batch-gradient-descent

I have been reading "drop" is a method to regularize model better. It's purpose is to update only some % of weights in backprop and it helps you to not over fit the model. But I am wondering, is this method useful in minibatch at all?

Answer (score 1):

Yes dropout is useful this case too. The purpose of dropout is to make the model generalize better by causing it to use **all available** weights from a given layer. It is supposed to make the subsequent layer **not rely on a small number of activations** from the previous layer, but to use them all.